# Why won't my external library method resolve?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, com, linker, atl

I have a DLL (`example.dll`) built in C which has this function in it:

```
void WINAPI free_job()
{
    lc_free_job(jobPtr);
}
```

I've built this DLL and linked `example.lib` into my Visual C++ project. Now I am trying to call the `free_job()` method on it from an ATL project with a simple COM object. Here is a part of my header that references the library:

```
#include "..\lib\example.h"
```

This is where I call it in my implementation:

```
STDMETHODIMP CCerberusSession::Free(CHAR* licensePath, CerberusErrorDetails* error)
{
    free_job();
    return S_OK;
}
```

It won't compile. I get the following errors:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall
>   free_job(void)" (?free_job@@YGXXZ) referenced in function "public:
>   virtual long __stdcall CCerberusSession::Free(char *,struct
>   CerberusErrorDetails *)"
>   (?Create@CCerberusSession@@UAGJPADPAUCerberusErrorDetails@@@Z)

What am I doing wrong and how can I troubleshoot or fix it? Any ideas would be helpful and appreciated.

**Edit**: I have tried to wrap the include like so:

```
extern "C" {
#include "..\lib\example.h"
}
```

But I get the following error if I try to compile it like this:

> Error MSB8011 Failed to register output. Please try enabling Per-user
>   Redirection or register the component from a command prompt with
>   elevated permissions.

I am running Visual Studio as an Administrator. What else could be wrong here?

Comment: Compiles just fine, it does not link.  Note the C++ name mangling in the linker error message.  C identifiers are not supposed to be mangled.  You need `extern "C" { }` around that #include.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks Hans. If I wrap the include, I now see a different error: `Error MSB8011 Failed to register output. Please try enabling Per-user Redirection or register the component from a command prompt with elevated permissions.` I have edited the question. Any ideas on what else could be the issue here? I am not sure but, does this have something to do with it being an ATL project and it failing to now register the output on the system? Does it have something to do with it not being able to resolve the included DLL? Any ideas would be a big help.

Comment: Completely different issue of course.  No idea what "elevated permissions" means?  It googles very well, try not to be helpless.

Comment: @HansPassant I am assuming elevated permissions means whether or not its being run as Administrator with Administrator privileges, which my instance of Visual Studio is running under in this case, so any process it spools up to register the output should also be under the same privilege scope. It must have something to do with registering my COM object...thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first issue was I needed to wrap that `#include` statement (thank you for pointing that out, Hans):

```
extern "C" {
#include "..\lib\example.h"
}
```

The second issue was due to `regsvr32.exe`. It can't find the dependent DLL which my application is importing because that DLL is not in the same output directory as my compiled ATL project. For example, if you check the `Output` tab in Visual Studio, you will see something like this:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1749,5): warning MSB3073: The command "regsvr32 /s "C:\Code\Cerberus\Debug\Cerberus.dll"" exited with code 3.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1761,5): error MSB8011: Failed to register output. Please try enabling Per-user Redirection or register the component from a command prompt with elevated permissions.
```

I just needed to include `example.dll` in the output directory: `C:\Cerberus\Debug\`.